# Macro changes Conditional Formatting that's already preset

Tags: vba, excel

I'm  running a Macro that creates a new workbook and a tab in that workbook based on a dropdown selection.  I'm running into issues with my conditional formatting. When I run the macro the conditional formatting rules are there but the color output changes.  For example I have a conditional formatting that changes a number green based on another value but after running the macro the color changes to Orange.  Doe's anyone know why?

Here's the code that I'm running

```
Sub BusinessPlan_Create()

Dim cell As Range
Dim counter As Long
Dim Dashboard As Worksheet
Dim newWB As Workbook
Dim wb1 As Workbook

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set newWB = Workbooks.Add
Set Dashboard = wb1.Sheets("Facility View")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each cell In wb1.Worksheets("dd").Range("$B3:$B87")
If cell.Value = "" Then
    counter = counter + 1
    Application.StatusBar = "Processing file: " & counter & "/1042"
Else
    counter = counter + 1
    Application.StatusBar = "Processing file: " & counter & "/1042"

    With Dashboard
    .Range("$B$1").Value = cell.Value
        With wb1
            .Worksheets("Facility View").Copy After:=newWB.Worksheets(1)
            ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
            ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd
            ActiveSheet.Name = cell.Value
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With
End If
 Next cell

 newWB.Activate

 Call SortWorkBook2

 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 Range("C6:D6").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Columns("C:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("C4").Select

Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: If the color palettes are different that will affect how it's colored. If there is special coloring in the first workbook that's not in the new that will not transfer over.

Comment: Also note that if `wb1` is not the active sheet, your copying/naming of the sheet, will occur on whatever sheet is active.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman no the coloring is simple like Green and Red.  The red seems to be unaffected but the standard green color is changing to orange